# Convert Mathematica equation to C/C++ expressions

Tags: output-formatting

I have written some mathematica-code which allows me to compute some equation in general relativity, which I would like to solve using a C++-program. However, the equations are roughly 1000 characters long. And since simple copy and past will not work because of mathematicas output-form, I was wondering if it would be possible to convert the equations in a simple way.

Comment: I used Mathematica to generate code for Asymptote, which uses a syntax similar to C. My strategy was to convert Mathematica code to string, and use `StringReplace` and `<>` to join additionnal strings. It is very far from being perfect but it worked in my case.

Comment: Have you searched the site yet? There are several related threads around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mathematica has an inbuilt function `CForm` which does a pretty good job. However, there are some caveats:

1. No support for Greek/special characters. Your variable names might have Greek characters, which are not supported in C/C++. Hence, you should replace all such variables. Create a list, maybe call it `subsGtoCpp`, put all rules which are required in list form.
2. `CForm` converts exponents to a form which is not compatible with C/C++. For example:

   CForm[x^2]

yields

> Power(x,2)

You can define a function `Power` in C++ which takes in two inputs, the variable and the index to which it is raised. The `Power` function can be overloaded to receive `int` and `double/float` inputs for the exponent and treat them accordingly. For `int` inputs you might want to use a `for` loop and the inbuilt `pow` function in-case of decimal exponents. One can simply replace `Power` in the expression generated from `CForm` to `pow` as well.

3. `x^2` has completely different meaning in C++.
4. Also, remember C++ is not for symbolic computation. So variables need to be initialized before using them.